# Custom icon for downloaded apk in system ui(notification area)

Tags: android, apk

How to accomplish this? User downloading apk outside google market, I want him to see custom icon for downloaded apk(prior installing).

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You might want read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/faq first. Improve you question and you might get more constructive answers.

Answer (score 2):

> User downloading apk outside google market, I want him to see custom icon for downloaded apk(prior installing).

If any `Notification` is shown, it will be from whatever app did the downloading. Normally, that will be the Downloads app, or perhaps the user's Web browser.

You are welcome to write your own app that can download files, in which case if the user uses your app to download the "apk", you can display whatever `Notification` you wish.

Otherwise, what you want is not possible, sorry.